How to draw first 5 minutes High and Low horizontal lines for the entire day at once, after first candle is closed?
The below Pine Script V5 code gives lines such as, Open, High, Low and Mid of first 5 minutes candle. But the line is getting plotted slowly, after every candle is closed. Means those lines are visible only up the candles closed or until the session time completed. I want that line to be plotted and visible for the entire day, immediately after first 5 minutes candles is closed. The session day starts at 9:15 am and closes at 15:30 pm. I have searched and I could not fine one code meets the requirement.
Here is the code, which plots lines only for the completed time period in a day.
indicator("Open and OR Lines", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 5000 , max_boxes_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500, max_lines_count = 500)

//Open Price Line and 5 Min Opening Range Lines

tz_increment = input.int(-4, 'UTC (+/-)', tooltip = 'New York is -4')
use_exchange = input(false, 'Use Exchange Timezone')

OR_sess = input.session('0915-0920', title='Opening Range Session')
OR_t = time(timeframe.period, OR_sess + ':1234567', use_exchange ? syminfo.timezone : 'GMT+0530')

show_mid = input.bool(true,"Show Mid levels")
chg_col = input.bool(true,"Level changes color", tooltip="Lines change color based on whether the   closing price is above or below the line")

var opening = 0.0

opening := OR_t and not(OR_t[1]) ? open : opening[1]

OR_in_session = not na(OR_t)
OR_is_first = OR_in_session and not OR_in_session[1]

OR_h = float(na)
OR_l = float(na)

if OR_is_first
    OR_h := high
    OR_l := low
    OR_l
else
    OR_h := OR_h[1]
    OR_l := OR_l[1]
    OR_l
if high > OR_h and OR_in_session
    OR_h := high
    OR_h
if low < OR_l and OR_in_session
    OR_l := low
    OR_l

OR_mid = (OR_h + OR_l) / 2

OR_line_col(_src)=>
    chg_col and close > _src ? #4caf4f : chg_col and close < _src ? #ff5252 : #dfc800b2


plot(timeframe.isintraday ? opening : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= #0703fc59, title='Opening price', linewidth=4)

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? OR_h : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= OR_in_session[1] or OR_in_session ? na : OR_line_col(OR_h), title='OR High', linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? OR_l : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= OR_in_session[1] or  OR_in_session ? na : OR_line_col(OR_l), title='OR Low', linewidth=2)
plot(show_mid and timeframe.isintraday ? OR_mid : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= OR_in_session[1] or OR_in_session ? na : OR_line_col(OR_mid), title='OR Mid', linewidth=1)

//################################

